# List the contents of a file on the form in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, directory

I was just wondering how do you display the conetnts of a chosen folder on a ListView or something for example so the files can be individually be selected (and multiple files)

At the moment i have a folder dialog where the user chooses their desired path and yeah have stopped there :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the string path you can use

[Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(VS.71).aspx)

and

[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)

to retrieve the contents of a folder.

Comment: Ahhh awesomee, seems like such a stupid question but ive been looking for it for too long and just got mental block loll.

Thanks Guys!! :D

Comment: dangit :( what makes his answer so much better than mine? :( mine was even submitted 50 seconds earlier.  Its his links isn't it? *sigh* defeated by his links...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to focus on your statement : "a Listview or something," and talk about the "something" scenario :)

Why aren't you using the built-in control 'OpenFileDialog : you can set the 'MultiSelect property to 'true and select all the files you like, you can filter the files that appear in complex ways, etc. : it's there, it's "free," it works.

If you specifically do not want to use this control for reasons like, for example, you want the list files to remain visible (i.e., not to be a modal interface) at all times, I suggest you clarify your original question to reflect that. The more you tell us exactly what you want, the more focused the answers you can get.

regards Bill,

Comment: Well the reason i didnt use the OpenFileDialog is because the files arent actually being opened they are being uploaded to a server, all i need to collect from the folder is the location and then the name and possibly some small over details then just upload the file to a server, the files can be multiply selected from loads of different folders which can all be viewed in the one list box.

I think im using the right method still right?

Ash

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(<filepath>)
```

will return a string array which you can iterate through and display file names.  It can be passed a true boolean value as well if you wish to do a recursive directory search.

If you wish to display directories as well, you will need to use

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(<filepath>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just call `ListView.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp");` the names of all files in c:\temp will be shown in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

All the cool kids use Linq :)

```
  var fileList = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\").GetFiles().Where(file => file.Extension == ".txt");
        foreach (var file in fileList)
        { 
            // Do what you will here
           // listView1.Items.Add(
        }
```

This just gets text files in the C:\ drive,  but you can tweak as necessary

Comment: Thats is an amazing peice of code!! Thankyou so much i was trying to remember how to select only certain file types from a folder but could remember, is there a waqy of selecting multiple types but specifying them?

Thanks,

Ash